# JCalendar get the current date clicked

Tags: java, jcalendar

So I have this

```
    @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            Date current = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

            if (calendar.getDate().after(current) || (calendar.getDate().getDate() == current.getDate()
                    && calendar.getDate().getMonth() == current.getMonth()
                    && calendar.getDate().getYear() == current.getYear())) {

                int month = calendar.getMonthChooser().getMonth() + 1;
                int day = (int) evt.getNewValue();

                String date = day + "/" + month;
                txtNothing.setText("Event:" + date);
                dispose();
            }
        }
    });
```

I know it can be better but this works for listening for a change in dates..

What can I use to get the current date selected when it is pressed again? currently that date is still highlighted but the propertychange event wont trigger when clicked the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a way to trigger it by using this

```
calendar.getDayChooser().setAlwaysFireDayProperty(true);
```